# Silverlight : Subtract key

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0

I have a handle for a currency value. It should allow negative value say -555.

On keydown/Keypress, when I try to find the Key value for Subtract key in Numpad, it gives me as Key.Subtract in IE versions. But in chrome/firefox latest versions, it shows me as Key.Unknown.

Is there any specific handle needs to be done.

Sample:

```
if ((e.Key >= Key.D0 && e.Key <= Key.D9) || (e.Key >= Key.NumPad0 && e.Key <= Key.NumPad9) || (e.Key == Key.Subtract) || (e.Key == Key.Unknown))
            {
                //valid number, but if shift is pressed, it is an invalied character
                if (Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Shift)
                    e.Handled = true;
            }            
            else
                e.Handled = true;
```

Here, I have handled the unknown key explicitly. But is there any standard way to get rid of this? Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have run into the same problem when some customers do not use IE. What you have to do is you have to check the value of PlatformKeyCode which has difference value on difference OS, for example, PlatformKeyCode of <kbd>.</kbd> is 190 on a Windows but it is 47 on Mac.

Below statement quoted from [KeyEventArgs.PlatformKeyCode Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyeventargs.platformkeycode%28VS.95%29.aspx) on MSDN.

> The portable key codes are a common subset of all the possible key
>   codes of the supported operating systems, in this case, Macintosh and
>   Windows. For example, the keystroke 'v' is represented as a Key value
>   (which would evaluate as 51 if you cast it to an integer, but is more
>   useful if you retain the enumeration information). That key would have
>   a PlatformKeyCode value of 86. Certain keystrokes, however, are not
>   portable, such as the SCROLL LOCK key for Microsoft Windows. In this
>   case, the Key value is Unknown, which is the value for any nonportable
>   key, and the PlatformKeyCode is 145 on a Windows platform. For
>   information about Microsoft Windows-specific key codes, see
>   "Virtual-Key Codes" in the MSDN Library. For information on
>   Macintosh-specific key codes, see Keyboard Layout Services Reference
>   on the Apple Developer Connection Web site.

On my machine the PlatformKeyCode value of <kbd>-</kbd> is 189.

Comment: Will this Platform key code change among different versions of same OS.. say Windows xp, 7 & 8 (now)... Or it is a common value for windows?

Comment: I have tested it with Windows XP, Windows 7, and Windows 8 they are all the same value.